# Problem with Maven in Spring roo

Tags: maven-2, spring-roo

I was trying to run the Wedding RSVP sample given with Spring Roo 1.0.0.RC3. I am running on Maven 2.2.1 and JDK 1.5.0_19, Java and M2 Home are properly set. Unfortunately none of the commands that involve Maven calls (example: "Perform test" or 'Perform eclipse") work and there is no error either. The cursor immediately returns on the roo command line. I also tried the steps at http://blog.springsource.com/2009/05/27/roo-part-2 but same problem. Did anybody face this issue?

Comment: @Debu Post your comment as answer and accept it. Or delete this question. But the first option is better IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aah, I guess this is a know bug and fixed in RC4 which is still not out. Here is the [JIRA issue](http://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-363).